# I want to create interval of 30 mins and limit the time to specific hours

Tags: java, android

I want to create interval of 30 mins and limit the time to specific hours in my project heres the java code

```
// CALLING 
initTimePicker();
        timebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                timepick.show();
            }
        });


private void initTimePicker(){
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                timebtn.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
            }
        };
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        int hrs=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int mins=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int style= THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;
        timepick = new TimePickerDialog(this,style,timeSetListener,hrs,mins,true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
// CALLING
initTimePicker();
timebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        timepick.show();
    }
});

private void initTimePicker(){
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // Check if the selected time is within your desired limits
            if (isTimeWithinLimits(hourOfDay, minute)) {
                timebtn.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
            } else {
                // Display an error message or handle it as needed
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid time selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hrs = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int mins = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int style = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog;
    
    // Set up a custom TimePickerDialog to allow 30-minute intervals
    timepick = new TimePickerDialog(this, style, timeSetListener, hrs, mins, true);
    
    // Set the time picker to allow 30-minute intervals
    timepick.setInterval(30);
}

private boolean isTimeWithinLimits(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Define your specific time limits here, for example, between 9 AM and 6 PM
    int lowerLimitHour = 9;
    int upperLimitHour = 18;
    
    // Check if the selected time is within the limits
    return hourOfDay >= lowerLimitHour && hourOfDay <= upperLimitHour && minute % 30 == 0;
}
```

Comment: timepick.setInterval(30);   // this line is getting red setInterval become red